# Adding fab Button at the junction of two ViewPager widgets

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I have implemented a navigation drawer. In the FrameLayout of navigation drawer I have added a fragment which contains 2 ViewPagers taking exactly half the screen each. Now I want to add a FAB button at the junction of these two viewpagers as shown here.

[image]

In my case both viewpagers occupy exactly half screen which is slightly different from what is shown in image. Can somebody help me in getting the FAB at the junction.

The code for the fragment containing the 2 viewpagers is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/shirt_section"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pant_section"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could enclose your linear layout into FrameLayout and add your button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

          ...
    </LinearLayout>  
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        ...
    />
</FrameLayout>
```